# Is Kinematic can't find in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have learned how to work with the unity on YouTube tutorial. I have a problem I can't see Is Kinematics Rigidbody 2D in my unity software but I see that in tutorial. Help me what can I do now......enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyulw.png)

Comment: It is unclear what your question is please see the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) quidlines to make clearer questions to help us help you

Answer (score 2):

This link might help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-find-the-iskinematic-on-off-pick.469802/
In unity 5.5, this option was moved to the body type dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly straight forward, if all is ok.

1. Add a gameObject to your scene and make sure it is selected.
2. Go to the inspector and click 'add component'
3. Search for rigid body.

Also see attache pickture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpFgE.jpg)

Hope this helps,
Kaz